# Include resource file available for download

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I am new to c# and I am almost done with a simple project. This project needs to include an excel file available for download using a `LinkLabel`

How can I include this file when compiling my project and when the `LinkLabel` is click it will as the user where to save the file.

My google search always point me to creating an excel, I dont need to create it, its already available, i just need to include in my resource file.

I am stuck here;

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Now its working fine with the below code, I cant answer my question yet due to low score.

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = null;
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            File.WriteAllBytes(@filePath, Properties.Resources.importPurchases);
            MessageBox.Show("File Successfully saved.\r\n\r\n" + filePath, "Success Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks to all who replied, its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the excel file to your `Project` (Add -> Existing Item).
2. Right Click the added Excel File, go to `Properties`
3. Set `Build Action` to `Content`
4. Set `Copy to Output Directory` as `Copy Always` or `Copy If Newer`

By doing this; the Excel File would be copied to the output folder always after build.

```
            var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "xls";
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls |All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                const string MyFileName = "myExcelFile.xls";

                string execPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

                var filePath = Path.Combine(execPath, MyFileName);

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Application();

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

                book.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName); //Save

                book.Close();
            }
```

**Update:** The above sample is for Windows Application...